# When running "serve -s build" to serve my React build folder locally, no content renders

Tags: reactjs

In my browser console, I get these errors:

Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'     2.e1e7f2e0.chunk.js:1

Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'     main.c36879cd.chunk.js:1

Manifest: Line: 1, column: 1, Syntax error.    :5000/React-Portfolio/manifest.json:1*

My app was built with create-react-app.  It runs fine locally when I'm not running from the build folder.  It has no back end.

Thoughts?

Comment: The `Unexpected token '<'` error is usually a sign that an HTML page (often an error page) is being returned instead of the requested file, try checking the response from those requests and see what's inside.

Comment: I've corrected the issue.  In my package.json, I removed "homepage." Everything works normally now.  I read about this in a post elsewhere.  Don't know why it works, but it does!

Answer (score 0):

I needed to remove "homepage" from my package.json.